# Mongodb Trying to get selected fields to return from aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm having trouble with my aggregate function. I'm trying to get the users most common orders from the database but I'm only returning the name and the count. I've tried using the `$project` operator but I can't seem to make it return anything other than what's in the `$group` statement.

Here is my current aggregate function:

```
OrderModel.aggregate(
        {$unwind: "$products"},
        {$match: { customerID: customerID }},
        {$group: { _id: "$products.name", count: {$sum:1}}},
        {$project: {name: "$_id", _id:0, count:1, active:1}},
        {$sort: {"count" : -1}},
        {$limit: 25 })
```

This just produces an output as follows `{"count":10, "name": foo"}` whereas I want to return the whole object; embedded docs and all. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Edit- Added example document and expected output

Document:

```
{
    "charge": {},
        "captured": true,
        "refunds": [
        ],
        "balance_transaction": "txn_104Ics4QFdqlbCVHAdV1G2Hb",
        "failure_message": null,
        "failure_code": null,
        "amount_refunded": 0,
        "customer": "cus_4IZMPAIkEdiiW0",
        "invoice": null,
        "dispute": null,
        "statement_description": null,
        "receipt_email": null
    },
    "total": 13.2,
    "userToken": "cus_4IZMPAIkEdiiW0",
    "customerID": "10152430176375255",
    "_id": "53ad927ff0cb43215821c649",
    "__v": 0,
    "updated": 20140701082928810,
    "created": 20140627154919216,
    "messageReceived": false,
    "ready": true,
    "active": false,
    "currency": "GBP",
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "Foo",
            "active": true,
            "types": [
                {
                    "variants": [
                        {
                            "name": "Bar",
                            "isDefault": false,
                            "price": 13.2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected outcome:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Foo",
        "active": true,
        "types": [
            {
                "variants": [
                    {
                        "name": "Bar",
                        "isDefault": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "variants": [
                    {
                        "name": "Something else",
                        "isDefault": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "quantity": 10
   },
   {
       "name": "Another product",
       "active": true,
       "types": [
           {
               "variants": [
                   {
                       "name": "Bar",
                       "isDefault": false
                   }
               ]
           }
       ],
       "quantity": 7
   }
```

]

Thanks!

Comment: Show a sample document from your collection. But if "customerID" is actually a grouping across documents then what you are doing will not work if you want the original documents back. Show source documents and your expected results.

Comment: @NeilLunn I've updated the post now. CustomerId is not a grouping across documents, just a field in this document.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Largely speaking here, [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) relies on the "absolute path" to the field property in the document on the "right hand" side. Shortcuts such as `1` are just for where that element is actually the top level of the document.

Also you need to be able to retain fields when you [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), so this is where you use various grouping operators such as [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) and [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) or [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) to keep the information you are puling from the inner array. And you must [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) twice here as well since you are combining "types" across documents, and you do not want just the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) in this case.

```
OrderModel.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$products" },
    { "$unwind": "$products.types" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$products.name",
        "active": { "$first": "$products.active" },
        "types": { "$addToSet": "$products.types" },
        "quantity": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "name": "$_id",
        "active": 1,
        "types": 1,
        "quantity": 1
    }}
],function(err,results) {

});
```