# Mongoose query nested json array, return selected fields

Tags: json, mongodb

I am new to mongo/mongoose (using version 3.4.0), and I would like to write a query that returns a subset of a document JSON array that matches a given criteria.
My document model contains an array of JSON, and I would like the query to only return the records in the array where a match occurs, and only specific fields.

Here is an example schema:

```
Var testSchema = Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  bag: { type: Array}  // JSON row data, containing fields name, phone, etc...
});
```

Example data:

```
name: "alpha",
bag: [ 
  { item:"apple", color:"red",   size:"small"},
  { item:"pear",  color:"white", size:"small"},
  { item:"apple", color:"green", size:"large"}
]

name: "beta",
bag: [ 
  { item:"apple", color:"brown", size:"small"},
  { item:"pear",  color:"white", size:"small"},
  { item:"apple", color:"green", size:"medium"}
]
```

Or

```
db.tests.insert({name:'alpha', bag:[{ item:'apple', color:'red', size:'small'},{ item:'pear', color:'white', size:'small'},{ item:'apple', color:'green', size:'large'}]})
db.tests.insert({name:'beta', bag:[{ item:'apple', color:'brown', size:'small'},{ item:'pear', color:'white', size:'small'},{ item:'apple', color:'green', size:'medium'}]})
```

I would like to be able to query this data, but only return the "bag" data that matches the query item:"apple" and only return the "item" and "color" fields from "bag".

```
Name: "alpha", bag: [{ item: "apple",  color: "red" }, { item: "apple",  color: "green" }]
Name: "beta", bag: [{ item: "apple",  color: "brown" }, { item: "apple",  color: "green" }]
```

I have tried using aggregate with match and project:

```
db.tests.aggregate([
    {"$match":{"bag.item":"apple"}},
    {"$project":{
        "Bag.item":{
            "$filter":{
            "input":"$bag",
            "As":"bag",
            "cond":{"$eq":["$$bag.item", "apple"]}
        }},
        "Bag.color":1
    }}]);
```

But this returns the color field for all items, not just apples, and still returns the size field.

I have seen these:

[Mongodb Trying to get selected fields to return from aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571978/mongodb-trying-to-get-selected-fields-to-return-from-aggregate)

[Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

but have still not figured out how to limit the items in the nested JSON array.

Comment: what is your mongodb server version ?

Comment: db.version() is 3.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation for 3.4 version. `$addFields` to overwrite the existing field `bag` with filtered array followed by `$project` with exclusion to drop the `size` field.

```
db.tests.aggregate([
    {"$match":{"bag.item":"apple"}},
    {"$addFields":{
        "bag":{
            "$filter":{
            "input":"$bag",
            "as":"result",
            "cond":{"$eq":["$$result.item", "apple"]}
        }}
    }},
    {"$project":{"bag.size":0}}
]);
```